# HTML Form Submission to Google Sheets using Apps Scripts Landing "Thank You" Page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I have setup a Google Apps Script as a WebApp to take form data from an HTML form (non-google form) and insert the results into Google Sheets. Everything is working, but I am trying to get a custom landing page instead of the current Apps Script page, which is not useful for the end user.

I used this for reference: https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet

There is some info at the end of this GitHub guide, but it is not descriptive and I cannot find anything that works here or on GitHub. I know some JS, but I am no expert and could really use a hand figuring this out. Below is what I have and this is the closest I have gotten to everything working.

Here is my HTML.

```html
<script>
function myFunction()
{ alert("The form was submitted successfully. Please press okay to continue...");
window.open("URL-to-thanks-page", "_top");
}
</script>

<form class="googleform" name="googleform" id="googleform" target="_top" method="POST" onsubmit="myFunction()" action="MY-GOOGLE-APPS-SCRIPTS-URL">
        <!--FORM STUFF-->
    <button type="submit" class="btn-default btn" name="submit" access="false" style="default" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Code.gs

```js
const sheetName = 'RSVP'
const scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  const activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    const doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    const sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    const headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    const nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    const newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'Date' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Respectfully,

Comment: From `onsubmit="myFunction()"`, can you provide not only HTML but also Javascript?

Comment: Yes, sorry, updated the original post with this info.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `<!--FORM STUFF-->`, in your actual situation, what are therein?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `doPost` instead of using [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)? In Apps Script, that is the recommended way to call a server-side function in most situations. Also, instead of opening the new page via `window.open`, I'd make the server-side function return the new page. If you think this approach could be useful to you, I'd consider providing an answer explaining this.

Comment: @Iamblichus I would be interested in that. I am no expert, but I am trying to get this working the best way possible. If you are willing to provide an answer explaining this, then that'd be very helpful

Comment: @Nathan Klayko Thank you for replying. I understood that my proposed workaround was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I don't want to confuse other users. So I have to delete my answer. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your help! @Tanaike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out actually. I used the code on the original guide with a modification. In my HTML I removed the previous `<script>` section and changed it to the following:

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('googleform');
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const action = e.target.action;
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
    .then(() => {
    window.location.href = 'URL of thank you page';
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

This fixed the issue and now everything is working correctly.

Comment: I made use of this code and found it useful, thank you... But  the ".then" part of the code caused a pretty major delay in redirecting to the thank you page. It seems to me that, in any case, this ".then" is not needed for the script to function. But perhaps the "fetch" should have some error handling (try / catch). Do you have any insight into this?